# How to debug Java thread death

Tags: java, multithreading, debugging

My program dies in a thread without throwing an exception right in the middle of my code. I tried to install an UncaughtExceptionHandler and capture exception but nothing is caught.

```
Thread.currentThread().setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new DeathWatcher());
try {
   LOG.info("Start =========");
   dyingMethod();
   LOG.info("End ==========="):
} catch (Throwable e)  {
    LOG.error(e.getMessage());
    throw e;
}
```

The code will print Start in the log but no End.

What would cause a thread to die before completion without an exception?

Comment: Is it possible that `dyingMethod()` results in a call to `System.exit()` somehow?

Comment: Is this a separately spawned thread or the main thread? You seem to already know which method or thread is dying - does this mean you know how to reproduce the problem?

Comment: That would cause the JVM to quit. The main thread is still running afterwards, just one thread dies.

Comment: Does your program actually exit, or does it get caught in a loop?

Comment: The program spawns a thread to run the `dyingMethod`. The thread dies but the program is still running.

Comment: Are you sure that thread died instead of hanging? have you created thread dump to be sure?

Comment: Yeah. I can confirm the thread is dead. I can see it disappear in Intellij debugger.

Comment: @ZZCoder Please provide a [reprex]. The code you've provided is insufficient to determine what's going on.

Comment: Sorry. I wasn't able to make a reproducible example without using some proprietary libraries. The problem is most likely in those libraries.